# LaTeX \chapter introduction

Tags: chapters

My supervisor wants me to write an introduction for each chapter, between the chapter number and the chapter title. I don't know how am I supposed to do it.This is what I want:

```
Chapter 2:
blabla
Title of Chapter 2
```

And I also want to have in my table of contents the following:
`2 Title of Chapter 2......... page 15`

This is what she wrote:
[image]

Comment: Such kind of writing is _very_ strange. The introduction should be after the chapter title I think

Comment: I think the same, but I edited the question so you can see it and maybe tell me what she wants...and how to do it

Comment: Of course I understand what she wants, but I just want to say that it is very strange, if 'terrible' is a too heavy word. I would never read a document like that

Comment: I know, I agree with you...but she decides about my marks ahah! Maybe she is telling that she wants the chapter number, then the intro to the chapter, then a section? but in this way the table of contents becomes a mess!

Comment: Usually the solution for questions like this depends to some (certainly not insignificant) degree on the document class you use. Maybe you could tell us more about that in a short example document (MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). The KOMA Script classes, for example, have some features that could be helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `memoir` class provides a macro `\afterchapternum` which inserts itself between the chapter number and the chapter title. The following, less any typos, is just to give you an idea.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{{\\ \normalsize\textit{In this chapter \ldots}\\}}
\chapter{first}
Some text.
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{\\ \normalsize\textit{But here \ldots}\\}}
\chapter{Second}
More text.
\end{document}
```

This produces text between the chapter number and the title, but does not add the text to the ToC. As given the layout of the inserted text is not pretty but I don't know what your supervisor wants, except that it is passing strange.

Define a macro that encompasses the desired layout of the inserted text and use that before each `\chapter`. For instance:

```
\newcommand{\chapintro}[1]{\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{{\\ \normalsize\textit{#1}\\}}}
```

Good luck with your supervisor.

Comment: many thanks, this is the thing which is nearest to the solution I need. I'll ask her if this is what she wants